# How can I align the bottom edges of two divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, alignment

I have several `div` boxes in different columns in a grid, and I would like to identify boxes where the bottom edge is less than 50px higher than any other box, and adjust its height to make sure they "align" at the bottom.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YFURR/

In that example I would like to identify that box1 and box4 have a bottom edge less than 50px from eachother, and extend the height of box4 to "snap" to the bottom edge of box1. Same with box2 and box5.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is way to vague, what happens if there is a waterfall of divs within 50px?

Comment: please provide us some stripped down HTML that shows us what you mean

Comment: as @koenp said, if you could reproduce an example in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or show html or images, it'd much easier to know what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Added a fiddle now, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking to do but css min-height might be what you are looking for.

```
your_selector {
    min-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a css of height:100%;

.mydivs { display:block; height:100%; }

for 100% height to work, also make sure your containing element has a height set